# Get topic name, partition and offset in case of container error handlers

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am getting deserialization exception while consuming data from Kafka topic.
I want to set the offset to current +1. I have an error handler at **container** level which takes exception, consumer record and consumer objects in argument. In the exception message I can see the topic, partition and offset. But **consumer record is null**. How can I get topic, partition and offset?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs before a `ConsumerRecord` is created.

Starting with version 2.2, you can configure the `ErrorHandlingDeserializer2` to wrap the real deserializer; the container then calls the error handler with a `DeserializationException` and you will get a `ConsumerRecord` witha `null` value.

The exception has the original `byte[]` in its `data` property.

Comment: Thanks @Gary. Then can I somehow increment my offset for that topic partition?

Comment: As long as the error handler "handles" the error (the default error handler just logs the exception), the container will commit the offset and move on to the next record.